# To separate code and document in Office automation

Tags: vba, ms-office, office-automation

I'm currently working on an vba project to help document developers do their work better and faster.

The tool is helpful during the developing, but however, it's no longer needed after the document is complete.

So, is there any ideas, about how to export a pure document without vba code automatically? Or shall I do this stupidly by opening vba and remove all of its code?

Further more, Is there any ways, to automatically apply vba code to an existing document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an add-in.  Your VBA code lives in the add-in, but operates on your documents.  The add-in can create a custom menu to run your various routines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thought I found it better to use vbe.